# Is there a way to add splash screen in java for react native project?

Tags: java, android, react-native, splash-screen

I have seen a lot of solutions using the `react-native-splash-screen` library for react native projects.

Is there any way to implement splash screen in android(java) for a react native project without using the `react-native-splash-screen` library or without any external libraries?

Comment: The library is open source - why not see how they did it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating a new java class with extends `AppCompatActivity` class. Then you need to modify the manifest XML file also by including this new activity. This Splash screen code need to be inside of `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout to display your Splash screen and then navigate to either Login or Homescreen as per your APP Navigation Routes. For Example`

```
class Splash extends Component{                  
  componentDidMount = () => {

    this._init()
}

_init = async () => {
    const userPrefs = await getUserPref();

    if (userPrefs !== null) {

        setTimeout(() => {
            
                this.props.navigation.replace('Home')
          
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.props.navigation.replace('Start')

        }, 1000);
    }
}


render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.parent}>

            <Image
                source={Images.logo}
                style={styles.logo}
                resizeMode='contain'
            />
            
        </View>
    )
}}
```